# React for loop runs twice with array values not filled properly

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, for-loop, frontend

React for loop run twice and Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop. only array with even index are assigned values .

```
 import logo from './logo.svg';
    import './App.css';
    import Board from "./components/Board";
    import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    
    
    function App() {
      const [candyArray, setcandyArray] = useState([]);
        let n = 8, arr = [], i;
        for (i = 0; i < (n * n); i++) {
          arr[i] = Math.floor((Math.random() * n));
          i++;
        }
        setcandyArray(arr);
      console.log(candyArray);
      return (
        <Board />
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Board js

```
export default function Board(props) {

    return (

        <div className="board">
            <div className="board-wrapper">
                <div className="candy-box" id="box1"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box2"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box3"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box4"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box5"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box6"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box7"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box8"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box9"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box10"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box11"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box12"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box13"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box14"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box15"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box16"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box17"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box18"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box19"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box20"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box21"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box22"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box23"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box24"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box25"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box26"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box27"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box28"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box29"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box30"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box31"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box32"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box33"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box34"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box35"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box36"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box37"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box38"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box39"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box40"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box41"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box42"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box43"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box44"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box45"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box46"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box47"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box48"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box49"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box50"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box51"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box52"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box53"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box54"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box55"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box56"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box57"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box58"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box59"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box60"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box61"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box62"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box63"></div>
                <div className="candy-box" id="box64"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

i want to make an array with values randomly filled between 0 to 7 and this array stored in state value(candyArray) in react.
thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have an unintentional side-effect in the component body. You likely are rendering you app into a `React.Strictmode` component that runs specific functions and methods twice as a way to help you detect unintnetional side-effect. One of these on-purpose double-invokations is the function body of function components. Since the side-effect is a state update this triggers a rerender. This is the render looping that React is complaining about.

Use a `useEffect` to run the effect once when the component mounts. Use a second `useEffect` hook to log when the `candyArray` state updates.

You also appear to be double incrementing your loop counter `i`, leading to only every other array element being updated. Remove the additional `i++` from the loop body.

```js
const Board = () => <div>Board</div>;

function App() {
  const [candyArray, setcandyArray] = React.useState([]);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    let n = 8, arr = [], i;
    for (i = 0; i < (n * n); i++) {
      arr[i] = Math.floor((Math.random() * n));
    }
    setcandyArray(arr);
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(candyArray.map((el, i) => `[${i}->${el}]`));
  }, [candyArray]);

  return (
    <Board />
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: @vardhaman Did you intend to double increment `i` each loop? Once in the for-loop function and once again in the loop body?

Comment: @vardhaman I see. Has my updated answer sufficiently addressed/resolved your question/issue?